# Java JCheckBoxMenuItem fire event only when selected

Tags: java, event-handling, jcheckbox

I have a JCheckBoxMenuItem inside a JMenu.
My task is simple: when it's selected, it should fire a DialogBox, in other words a JFileChooser. When it's unselected, do nothing.
PROBLEM: it works fine when it's selected, but it keep doing the same when unselected.

This is the code:

```
JCheckBoxMenuItem checkBox = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("ChebkBox");
    checkBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent arg0) {
            if(checkBox.isSelected())
            {
                System.out.println("SELECTED!");
                checkBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                        JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
                        if (fileChooser.showSaveDialog(checkBox) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                            //DIALOG BOX CODE....
     });
```

I'm not sure where the issue is, maybe it's related to the action lister which is nested. It's fired even when the checkbox got unselected.
Is there a way so solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you are checking isSelected in wrong place.
you should check the Selection inside actionPerformed.

```
checkBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent arg0) {
                System.out.println("SELECTED!");
                checkBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                        if (checkBox.isSelected()) {
                            if (fileChooser.showSaveDialog(checkBox) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                                // DIALOG BOX CODE....
                            }
                        }
                    };
                });
            }
        });
```